# Why can't I easily customise Meta TITLE, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE of Facebook Share if it's a Facebook App/Tab that I'm sharing?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook Tab (also called an app these days) that sits in a Facebook 'business' page as a tab and lives inside the usual facebook iFrame.

There is a Share button at the bottom for users to share the Tab/app.

I want to customise the content of the pop up dialog box.

There is a new and easy way to customise the Title, Description, Image and anything else - simply have OG Meta tags in the header of the page.

These are ignored in this instance because the share button only scrapes the top meta tags which occur outside the tab's iFrame.

Surely this is a huge oversight on Facebook's part?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an external URL with the Open Graph Tags and redirect to the Page Tab with JavaScript. This is the recommended way anyway, because Page Tabs don´t work on mobile, so you can just NOT redirect on mobile devices and show the Tab directly without Facebook.